# Accessing .lck and jdb files stored via web crawler

Tags: java, parsing, web-crawler, crawler4j

I'm currently using [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) as my web crawler of choice, and I am trying to teach myself how web crawlers work. I've started the crawl and I expected it to quickly return the crawled data at crawlStorageFolder (/data/crawl/root) seen below

```
public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


            /*
             * crawlStorageFolder is a folder where intermediate crawl data is
             * stored.
             */
            String crawlStorageFolder =  "/data/crawl/root";


            /*
             * numberOfCrawlers shows the number of concurrent threads that should
             * be initiated for crawling.
             */
            int numberOfCrawlers = 7;



            CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();

            config.setCrawlStorageFolder(crawlStorageFolder);
```

Problem is that the only information I could find are two .lck files and one .jdb file at crawlStorageFolder location which I am assuming is where the data is stored, but I am unable to open them up as well. Would someone be as kind enough to help me understand how I can access the data so that I can hopefully and successfully get it into an database and eventually display it on my website. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Crawler4j uses [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) to store crawl informations. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/frontier/InProcessPagesDB.java) in the source.

From the command line you can use DB utils to acces the data. Already covered in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644/examining-berkeley-db-files-from-the-cli).

If you want to access the data in your Java code, you simply import BerkeleyDB library (Maven instruction [there](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/maven-087630.html)) and follow the [tutorial on how to open the DB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/collections/tutorial/opendatabases.html).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't work with the data in that folder. You should consider that data as crawler's internal data. You can always dump/write your crawling data in the WebCrawler's visit method.